# WP Как убрать значение таксономии из URL адрессной строки?

Tags: wordpress, url

Есть вот такая кастомная таксономия. Созданная в `functions.php` для записей `post_type=>'projects'`

```
/// Registered Taxonomy 'project_type'
function create_projects_type_taxonomy() {
    $labels = array(
        'name' => __('Project Types', 'am'),
        'singular_name' => __('Project Type', 'am'),
        'search_items' => __('Search Project Types', 'am'),
        'all_items' => __('All Project Types', 'am'),
        'parent_item' => __('Parent Project Type', 'am'),
        'parent_item_colon' => __('Parent Project Type:', 'am'),
        'edit_item' => __('Edit Project Type', 'am'),
        'update_item' => __('Update Project Type', 'am'),
        'add_new_item' => __('Add New Project Type', 'am'),
        'new_item_name' => __('New Project Type Name', 'am'),
        'menu_name' => __('Project Types', 'am'),
    );

    $args = array(
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'labels' => $labels,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => array(
            'slug' => false,
            'hierarchical' =>false,
        ),
    );

    register_taxonomy('project_type', array('projects'), $args);
}

add_action('init', 'create_projects_type_taxonomy', 0);
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли возможность убрать из `URL` адрессной строки эту вставку про тип такономии ? В документации [register_taxonomy](https://misha.agency/wordpress/register_taxonomy.html#rewrite) не нашел, как отключить slug но при этом не превращать адрессною строку в GET параметр.

[image: Таксономия]

Comment: Есть, но это плохая практика. [https://www.kobzarev.com/wordpress/woocommerce-kill-performance/](https://www.kobzarev.com/wordpress/woocommerce-kill-performance/)